# "async def" command always pops up a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-asyncio, discord.py

I'm trying to write a bot for my Discord server, and I'm following a tutorial from Issuehunt. I've gotten around the `discord.py` rewrite and whatnot, but there's an odd syntax error that keeps happening.
The command looks a little something like this:

```
@bot_command()
   async def info(ctx)
```

...and then all the extra stuff that isn't important. When I run the code (either in the shell or through Command Line,) it says this:

```
  File "C:\Users\samsl\Documents\Hyperbot\hyperbot-v0_01.py", line 16
    async def info(ctx)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've typed everything well, imported both `disscord.py` and `asyncio.py` using PIP, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a `:` at the end of the line

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: In addition to missing colon, the indentation doesn't look correct - the `async def` should be on the same indentation level as the decorator above it (i.e. "a" in "async" should be under "@" in "@bot_command").

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, two things:
1) Always end your function delcaration with a : 
2) your decorator (@bot.command()) and function must be on the same indentation level.

Your code should look like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx):
```